# LUIS v2.0 EndPoint - JSON Result Inconsistency

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

Netwonsoft.JSON throws and exception when Deserializing the results from LUIS especially for builtin.datetimeV2.date.

The JSON shape is inconsistent between various entity type and it is unable to process the JSON.

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'entities[0].resolution.values', line 15, position 11.)'

When the Entitytype is builtin.datatimev2.date, the resolution segment of the JSON is a key value pair, while when the Entity type is custom or builtin.keyPhrase, the resolution is just values. This throws an exception at the time of Deserializing.

Any chance it can all be consistent across Entity types?[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. The JSON object is really a data type definition. Each entity type has different information that needs to be returned. It would probably be better to construct the NewtonSoft model in such as way that the entities array item is a string or generic object. Your code will have to convert it based on what items are in the object. You might look at [BotFramework 4.x for C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Ai.LUIS) and see how it was handled there.